# Making the jenkins build failure if cypress TC failure

Tags: jenkins, cypress, mochawesome

Currently , my cypress testes are runnning in docker container on one stage

```
    stage('Run E2E tests') {
     steps {
        withCredentials([
          sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: '*********', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY_FILE', usernameVariable: 'SSH_USER')
         ]) {
        sh """
            eval `ssh-agent -s`
            ssh-add ${SSH_KEY_FILE}
            ~/earthly \
              --no-cache \
              --config=.earthly/config.yaml \
              +e2e
            eval `ssh-agent -k`
          """
        }
      } 
    }
```

And publishing the test report to via publishHTML.

```
post {
    always {
      echo "-- Archive report artifacts"
      archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'results', allowEmptyArchive: 'true'
      echo "-- Publish HTLM test result report"
      publishHTML (target: [
            allowMissing: false,
            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
            keepAll: true,
            reportDir: 'results/html/',
            reportFiles: 'mochawesome-bundle.html',
            reportName: "Test Result Report"
          ])
    }
  }
```

But i need to make the build failure if any of the TC failure in the cypress mocha report

what can be the solution for this..?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you trying to report the failure to? What is currently being reported?

Comment: @agoff : Currently the Build is getting success , irrespective of TC success/failure. i would like to make the build as red[failure] if one of the TC failure

Comment: I am trying add one more stage to validate the console output from build
stage('CheckLog') {
      steps {
        if (manager.logContains('.*myTestString.*')) {
          error("Build failed because of this and that..")    
        }
      }

will this approach will work..?

Comment: So you just want to mark the Jenkins build as failed if any test cases fail?

Comment: Yes , that is my plan @agoff

Comment: Is there any possibility of you also generating a `junit` result? Jenkins most easily accepts JUnit XML files as test results, so if you can generate that, and then report it to Jenkins, it should already mark the build as Unstable.

Comment: I have to check , that option. current cypress is throwing in  different format

Comment: Cypress has a `junit` reporter built in, but I know that generating multiple reports can be tricky.

Comment: @agoff : looks like i dont have other choice , adding junit based report , will update if it is success. Appreciate the responses